# Como faço para percorrer a lista Select

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```js
    <script>
    function check(){
        var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#cidade").value;
        var reg = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        
        console.log(reg.exec(verificaInput))
        console.log(reg.test(verificaInput))

    }

        
    function changecidades(){
        var selectedoption = document.getELementById(optionvalue)
        console.log(changecidades())
        for(i = 0, i < selectedoption, i++){
        

            }
    }

    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
    <select id="optionvalue" onchange="changecidades(this.value);">
            
            <option value= "0">São Paulo</option>
            
            
            
            <option value="1">Jundiaí</option>
            
            
            
            <option value="2">Casa Branca</option>
            
            
            
            <option value="3">Campinas</option>
            
            
            
            <option value="4">Sorocaba</option>
        
        
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="agencia" id="cidade"/>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="conta" id="id"/>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="click to check" onclick="check(this.id)"/>
    </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pessoal, boa noite! por favor, como fariam pra percorrer a opção do select e verificar um Regex de 2 números entre 0-9 para cada cidade, parei na parte do for.

Obrigado.

Comment: Como assim "regex de dois números"? Quer dizer que os valores só podem ter exatamente dois dígitos, ou é no máximo dois?

Answer (score 0):

**Você pode percorrer no elemento `option` do seu `select` e fazer uma Iteração** nele usando, por exemplo, o laço de repetição `for`.

Ele tem vários atributos, como value ou text.

> O value pega o valor da tag `<option value"">`
>  O text pega o
>   MyText:`<option value"">MyText</option>`

```js
//O seu select:
var selectedoption = document.getElementById("optionvalue");
//As opções do seu select. Isto aqui é uma coleção:
var options = selectedoption.options;
```

```js
function check(){
        var verificaInput = document.querySelector("#cidade").value;
        //Tá okay
        var reg = /^[0-9]{4}$/;
        
        if(reg.exec(verificaInput)!==null){
          //Se for igual a true
          if(reg.test(verificaInput)){
            //Seu código aqui
            console.log("Passou");
          }
        }
        else{
          alert("Algum código");
        }
        
    }

        
    function changecidades(){
        var selectedoption = document.getElementById("optionvalue");
        //A coleção de option do seu select
        var options = selectedoption.options;
        //options.length: pega a quantidade
       for(var i = 0; i < options.length;i++){
          console.log(options[i].value);
        }
        
    }
    
    //Usando JQUERY:
    $("#optionvalue").change(function(){
    //
       changecidades();
    });
 
 //Seu botão check
    document.getElementById("buttonCheck").onclick = function(){
        check();
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>test</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <label>
    <select id="optionvalue">
            <option value="">Selecione...</option>
            <option value= "0">São Paulo</option>
            
            <option value="1">Jundiaí</option>
            
            <option value="2">Casa Branca</option>
            
            <option value="3">Campinas</option>
            
            <option value="4">Sorocaba</option>
        
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="agencia" id="cidade"/>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="conta" id="id"/>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="buttonCheck" value="click to check"/>
    </label>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**REFERÊNCIAS:**

1. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp
2. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_option.asp
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option